# Word for "other people who have the same issue/problem as I have"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

This is for a tech support or customer support case. I need a single-word tag labeling other people who share my issue.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE!  Unfortunately, I'm not clear on the details here.  Are you support or a customer?  Are you wanting to refer to support personnel or customers?

Comment: Here's the use case: I'm a customer on a social support network. I'm searching for a solution to my problem. I find that someone has already posted my problem: "My battery died. What do I do?". I'm curious how popular the problem is so I and want to see a tiny stat showing how many other people share my problem (e.g. "15 people share this issue") in one word (e.g. "15 blank").

Comment: Is "15 similar issues" or "15 identical issues" short enough?

Comment: Ehm, not being too serious about this, but maybe, ehm: A duplicate (?)

Answer (score 7):

You might use "users affected" or "users impacted." (Or simply "affected" or "impacted," but those look a little awkward, not technically being nouns.)

Comment: I don't think so.  This would mean that this number of users are impacted or affected by one person's dead battery; not each by their own dead battery.

Comment: @DavidWallace, A dead battery is not an issue that can be shared, which is the OP's specific case. The recent iOS 5 battery problems are, and many users were affected by this bug/issue. The more distant iPhone 4 antenna problems were a hardware issue that affected some users.

Answer (score 6):

It may reek of legalese, but I think ***co-complainant*** pretty well covers it.

Comment: The word does have a legal smell to it, but it's accurate and unambiguous. Most of the other similar terms seem to miss the mark with their meanings.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your use case, here are some suggestions:

- corroborators
- endorsers
- followers
- cases, incidences

Comment: Shouldn't that be instances rather than incidences? Incidences is a very rarely used word that is used when comparing multiple incident rates.

Answer (score 4):

How about "commiserators"? Not *exactly* what you're looking for, but it's kind of close.

[Webster.com definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commiserate):

> Commiserate -  to feel or express sympathy

Although I feel the connotations are usually more along the lines of what you are looking for.

[Thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commiserator) says:

> Commiserate (v.intr.) To feel or express sympathy: *commiserated over their failure.*

Answer (score 4):

*Victims* could fit.  It's a little overstated but it covers the idea.

Comment: I love the idea of *victims* if the tone of the company allows for humor. That would opens up many more possibilities: 15 *whiners*, *Round Tuits* (referencing the well known joke of 'when I get around-to-it'), *agitators*, *rabble-rousers* also  reported the issue. Such a style is common with comments links in blogging platforms, where the link will sometimes be styled to say *15 pieces of wisdom contributed by your fellow readers* or *15 angry missives typed by monkeys* depending on the theme and tone of the site.

Answer (score 3):

*Repro* is often used as a noun in tech support to mean other occurrences of the identical problem (although not the person having the problem).

Answer (score 3):

How about "sympathisers", because they can sympathise with you because they have had the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

*Co-sufferers* might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole vocabulary for such issues in ITIL.  You are referring to several incidents with a common problem.  For anyone doing your kind of job I would really recommend an ITIL fundamentals course.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library

and in particular  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incident_management_%28ITSM%29

A grasp of the key terms is essential if you're looking at reviews of any kind of service desk, CMDB, problem tracking etc software.

eta: sorry, just re-read and saw you're a customer.  It's late.  Anyway hopeful the site's admins have heard of ITIL

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine suggests "issue cousin."

Answer (score 1):

We used the word "incidents" to track the number of occurrences of the problem as opposed to tracking the number of users affected.

Answer (score 0):

*Class* reeks less of legalese than a previous answer, and its definition from Merriam-Webster Unabridged fits what you're looking for:

> Class is a very general term for **a group including all individuals
>   with a common characteristic.**

Answer (score 0):

"15 people share this issue" => "15 similarities"

"15 people share this issue" => "15 relatives"

"15 people share this issue" => "15 peers"

In the context you want to tag something, I believe one of these three would make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You migh consider pressing the word "comrade" (as in "comrades-in-arms", as in, humorously, "comrades up in arms" about this issue) into service for this purpose, e.g., "15 comrades".

Answer (score 0):

New York Times reports:

> ...
>
> There has always been, at the very least, a little bit of hate between
>   blacks and whites in this country, with each side, in its turn, taking
>   advantage of its political strength (as who does not?). But that
>   relationship is also perhaps like a marriage. Both sides at different
>   times are bitching, and both at different times are bailing, but ***we’re
>   all in the same boat***.
>
> We are bound to each other, as are all Americans. Bound though
>   subdivided, not only by race, but by religion, politics, age, region
>   and culture. And we not only seem to be but are working it out.
>
> ...

Here "***we’re all in the same boat***" means *people who have the same issue/problem*; hence a single-word tag labeling "other people who share my issue" might be "**navigant**" (or "**navigator**"); althoug I suggest you "NAVIGATOR-ADVICE", which is more comprensible.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest:

1. [groupers](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grouper)
2. [cohort](https://www.google.com/search?q=cohort&oq=cohort&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.2260983j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)
3. [cohors](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cohors)

Answer (score -3):

I think *agreers* might work as the word.

This is a word used to group people, used in demographics. Secondly, the word is for a group people who share the same problem. *Co-complainant*/*issue-brothers* etc., while not incorrect, didn't seem intuitive. Thirdly, I tried to apply *agreers* in possible contexts related to problem sharing, and found it fit.

Comment: Please [edit] in some examples of how you have used it.